# Dynamically Update a Certain Container with AJAX Update

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I have a list of Divs in my code

```
<div id="results">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Through JavaScript, I have an Ajax.Updater that will load results from an action. Depending on the selections a user makes from a multiple select dropdown, the Updater will be called many times and should place the results in the appropriate Div Tag (1, 2, or 3 depending on the dropdown value).

```
function loadData(){
var selections = ($(dropDown).selectedOptions);
for(var i=0; i<selections.length; i++){
     var divTag = 'div'+selections[i].value;

     new Ajax.Updater(divTag, './dataLoadAction', {
         method: 'post',
         insertion: Insertion.Bottom,
         parameters: {parameter: selections[i].value},

         onSuccess: function(){alert('Complete');}, 
         onFailure: function(){alert('ERROR');}
    });
}
}
```

However much I try though, the Ajax.Updater does not recognize anything other than a straight string in the container (divTag) parameter. Is there a way to dynamically declare what section the Ajax.Updater will Update?

UPDATE: I have fixed the problem by taking the divTags out of the "results" div ID. The Updater now matches the results to the appropriate divs.

Comment: What framework are you using to make the divs into a select? Select2 or something?

Comment: I'm using XSLT framework

Comment: Does not ring a bell. See my answer for an idea of how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some kind of framework that turns your divs into a select, and assuming `$(dropDown).selectedOptions` returns an array

```js
cnt = 0, selections;

function updater() {
  if (cnt >= selections.length) return; // stop;
  var divTag = 'div' + selections[cnt].value;

  new Ajax.Updater(divTag, './dataLoadAction', {
    method: 'post',
    insertion: Insertion.Bottom,
    parameters: {
      parameter: selections[cnt].value
    },

    onSuccess: function() {
      console.log('Complete');
      cnt++;
      updater();
    },
    onFailure: function() {
      console.log('ERROR');
    }
  });
}

function loadData() {
  selections = $(dropDown).selectedOptions;
  cnt = 0;
  updater();
}
```

Comment: I can update the results successfully into 
new Ajax.Updater('results', './dataLoadAction', { ... }
but am only having difficulty replacing 'results' with a dynamic divTag variable to help with ordering. I am unclear how this code would help with that.

Comment: What does `console.log('div' + selections[cnt].value);` show?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by taking the divTags out of the "results" div ID. The Updater now matches the results to the appropriate divs.